# How to store all the text files of its pickle file into its appropriate folder?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, pickle

There are a few pickle files, I exported their respective text files. I need to store these text files into a folder where the pickle file and its corresponding text files should exist.

For example:
There is a folder A, the pickle for this is A.pkl and the text files for this are A-1.txt, A-2.txt.
The folder A should contain A.pkl, A-1.txt and A-2.txt in it.

In the logic which I wrote, there is a folder being created for every text file.

```
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import move
path_to_files = Path(r"/home/abc/Desktop/qwerty/op")
for txt_path in path_to_files.glob("*.txt"):
    dir_path = path_to_files / txt_path.stem
    dir_path.mkdir()
    move(txt_path, dir_path / txt_path.name)
```

Could anyone please help me with this logic?

Comment: What happened when you ran that code?

Comment: @Cobra i got each text file in each folder. for example: A-1 folder and A-1.txt in it. A-2 folder and A-2.txt inside it. but i want both A-1.txt and A-2.txt in a single folder A.

Comment: It's unclear. Provide a [mre], including your input and output directory structures. Do you want to create a directory of the same name(without an extension) as a pickle file, for each pickle file? Then why do you do ```glob('*.txt')```, instead of ```glob('*.pkl')```?